# Does Blend still limit the user to moving at half speed, even if they have the talent Fast Stealth?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, rogue, stealth

Does [Blend](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blend/) still limit the user to moving at half speed, even if they have the talent [Fast Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/fast-stealth-ex/) or does the rogue talent supersede the limits of the spell?

Answer (score 5):

### Blend only works at half speed.

[Blend](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blend/) works "only while you move no more than half your base speed or less", and [Fast Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/fast-stealth-ex/) only remove the -5 penalty to [Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth) for going too fast (more than half-speed).

Your rogue knows how to move quickly without noise, but his active camouflage (*[MGS4-style](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/File:Snake_using_Octocamo_(Metal_Gear_Solid_4).png)*) isn't fast enough to keep up.

Comment: Yeah. that Makes sense, but still thought it could potentially be something worth asking. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and/or accept the answer if you find it satisfactory (though it's customary to wait a bit before accepting in case a better answer come up).